# dns dnssec-validation error centos

Tags: dns, centos

i have problem with Caching DNS Server in Centos7,when i try the dig command example

```
dig www.google.com
```

I get this output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7 <<>> www.google.fr
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 54269
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.fr.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.100#53(192.168.0.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 14 06:26:02 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

but when i change the dnssec-validation to no in the /etc/named.conf it work fine. any help

```
dig www.google.com
```

I get this output

```
dig google.com


; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39355
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.30
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.54
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.29
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.25
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.50
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.59
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.24
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.40
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.34
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.44
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.20
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.45
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.49
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.39
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.35
google.com.             92      IN      A       41.201.129.55

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       169937  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       169937  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 85 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.100#53(192.168.0.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 14 04:44:52 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 506
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). From your current question, it is unclear what exactly you're asking. Please clarify the problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to inform every one that the problem is solved, my lab was on Vmware workstation 12 but when i moved to Kvm everything worked fine, unbound and named both worked as expected and i didn't need to turn off dnssec-validation for named.